# Convertir JSONObject a arrayList en java

Tags: java, json, eclipse, jsonobject

Tengo un proyecto en **java** con **spring** y **backbone**, necesito pasar a `ArrayList` el resultado de una consulta para así mostrar un calendario con `FullCalendar` actualmente mi código es este agradezco toda la ayuda:

En mi Controlador:

```
@GetMapping("calendar")
public ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>> calendario(){
    System.out.println("calendario ");

    List<JSONObject> auditorias = mapaService.calendario();
    return new ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>>(auditorias,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

En mi service:

```
@Override
public List<JSONObject> calendario() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if(!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)){
        List<JSONObject> calendario = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

        ArrayList<Auditorias> auditorias = mapaDAO.calendario();

        JSONObject objetoJson;
        for(Auditorias auditoria : auditorias){
            objetoJson = new JSONObject();
            objetoJson.put("id", auditoria.getId());
            objetoJson.put("title", auditoria.getProveedor());
            objetoJson.put("start", auditoria.getFecha()+" 00:00:00");
            objetoJson.put("end", auditoria.getFecha()+" 21:59:00");
            objetoJson.put("color", auditoria.getColor());
            calendario.add(objetoJson);
        }
        System.out.println("objetoJson "+calendario);

        return calendario;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Error inicial:**

El error estaba en **calendario.add(objetoJson);** arrojaba:

"The method add(Auditorias) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (JSONObject)"

**Al hacer el cambio sugerido:**

Ahora arroja este error (tuve que cambiar el retorno de mi función en el controlador a **JSONObject** probablemente tenga que ver con este error, antes era un List de auditorias)

**mensaje Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])**

>

¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Estas tratando de agregar a una lista de tipo Auditorias un objeto de tipo JSONObject, por lo cual ese código ni debe compilar. ¿Para que creas una lista si luego no la usas? Quizás deberías dar un poco mas de contexto para ayudarte.

Comment: bueno tengo dos listas, una para recuperar los datos que me retorna la consulta en mapaDAO.calendario() y otra a la que pretendo pasar el JSONObject que armo dentro del for, al final lo que necesito es un conjunto de arrays en formato json para imprimir un calendario con FullCalendar

Comment: Si necesitas una lista en formato json, entonces deberias devolver una lista de tipo JSONObject, no de auditorias, salvo que la conversion de objeto a json se resuelva en otra capa... pero bueno no conozco la arquitectura de tu sistema. Para tu error de compilación debes cambiar esto:
List<JSONObject> calendario = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

Comment: bueno gracias, he hecho lo que me indicas y efectivamente ya no da error al compilar, el caso es que ahora me da un error muy extraño al intentar cargar el calendario, acabo de actualizar la pregunta con más datos

Comment: Yo lo que hago es que transformo el objeto de java a una Json-String  con el objectMapper -> mapper.writeValueAsString(obj); Después convierto esa String con formato Json a cualquier Objeto que en su clase cumpla con los campos del Json String con objectMapper readValue (obj, ClaseDeseada.class)